# What is this book about the Avar and Khazar Turks from the early 20th century?

Tags: middle-ages, russia, hungary

I came across a book on the internet that connected the Avars to the Khazars. It was written sometime during the 1920's-40's, I think the mid 20's, by a European scholar. It never became popular. This was a while ago, and now I can't find anything like it. It's left me with that weird feeling where I question if I'm making it up. I don't remember the language. What I remember is that I saw it on a website, along with a picture of him or his book, which was yellow and orange.

He said that the Avars who invaded Europe were essentially the same people as the Khazars. I'm interested in the possibility that there was a shared interest in the Turkic elements in the Avar and the Khazar Khaganates.

What is the book that I'm thinking of? The only way that I can think of to find it, is to sift through all of the Eastern European Turkic or Slavic scholars. Maybe the book title included Khazars, Avars, or Khazaria.

Comment: Was this book specifically about Avars or Khazars? My first guess about possible authors would be either [Inostrantsev](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Иностранцев,_Константин_Александрович) - but he did not write anything dedicated to Avars/Khazars. Or [Artamonov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikhail_Artamonov) - his fundamental monograph "History of Khazars" came in 1962 (but he is who actually excavated Sarkel in 1930s so some writings could come earlier).

Comment: Although if the book said exactly like *Avars ... were essentially the same people as the Khazars* in oppose to "Avars, Bulgars and Khazars are related" (or a sort of) -  that barely could be someone of the Russian/Soviet historical school of these years.

Comment: [For example](http://elib.shpl.ru/ru/nodes/3955-artamonov-m-i-ocherki-drevneyshey-istorii-hazar-l-1936#page/4/mode/inspect/zoom/4) (it's only the title in French, the book itself is in Russian. I'm not aware if there were any translations at all).

Comment: Thanks for the interest. I might have be mistaken but I didn't think he was Russian. I know the book was not in Russian. I have added more in the question about why I am interested

Comment: I think it was focused on the Avars. I also think that people knew back then that all these people were related, so that wouldn't have been an original idea worth writing a book about, rather it was more of a direct connection. @seven-phases-max

Comment: @JohnDee - I don't suppose you remember the publisher, or perhaps, where it was published?

Comment: Was the book in English?

Comment: "I don't remember the language".